# What's the purpose of the diode in this selectable supply voltage circuit part

Tags: power, diodes

I'm looking at the power supply part of the [schematic](http://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Dev/Arduino/Boards/Pro_Micro_v13.pdf) of SparkFun's Pro Micro Arduino board, which has a jumper to enable or disable a voltage regulator to select between running the board at 3.3V or 5V:

[image: Power supply part of circuit]

I have two questions about D2:

- What is its function in the circuit? Where can I read up on the motivation for adding it to the circuit? What would happen without it, and is it needed if I always want to run the board at 3.3V, i.e. if I omit the jumper?
- What kind of diode would I use if I build this board myself?

Comment: There is a much better way to do this, especially if battery powered (every watt lost is a kitten lost! Or time, at least) using a PFET "backwards" from the usual high side power switch configuration, and with the gate to ground. Same behaviour as the diode shown, but almost zero lost power during normal conditions in comparison. Check this youtube video for explanation https://youtu.be/IrB-FPcv1Dc

Comment: Err... The comment on the circuit reads "VCC = 5V or 3.3V out, max voltage input: 16VDC". However, if SJ1 is closed, Vout=Vin. But Vout is supposed to be 5V, yet Vin can go up to 16V? Oops.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The schematic has a note right on it:

[image]

So the fuse and diode are intended for protection (overcurrent and reverse voltage respectively), as others have correctly noted.

Note also that the diode drops about 0.65V or about half of the 1.7V that is required to get from 5V to 3.3V. At the maximum 500mA out, the power dissipation in the regulator will thus be split between the diode and the regulator at about 325mW each. That might be significant in allowing more current or higher ambient temperature, depending on what package that Sparkfun used.

If you build the circuit yourself, the diode is optional if you don't want the protection and are okay with the increased power dissipation. If you use a diode, a reasonable type to choose would be rated at 1A and 200V or more. Very common and cheap- a 1N4004 (1A/400V) would be a popular through-hole part.

Comment: I appreciate all the other answers as well, I picked this one as accepted because it's very detailed and provides some specific guidance about power dissipation and which diode could work.

Answer (score 3):

D2 protects the MIC chip from a reverse (wrong polarity) input voltage. It must be rated to block the expected input voltage, and to conduct the expected input current.

In this circuit which has a polyfuse I might have put the diode anti-parallel on the chip power, to avoid the voltage drop.

Comment: I re-read this and was wondering: by "anti-parallel on the chip power", did you mean as a crowbar circuit, where D2 is replaced with a wire and the diode instead connected with the anode to GND and the cathode to the right hand side of the fuse?

Comment: correct (that assumes that the diode and polyfuse can for the short time it takes the polyfuse to trip handle the peak current delivered by the power source).

Answer (score 2):

The diode is for reverse polarity protection - so you don't blow up the board if you connect the power supply the wrong way around. It is bypassed when you use the circuit in direct 5V mode, since that mode is essentially there to let you have more control over the power supply used.

If you are sure you aren't going to reverse connect the power (e.g. keyed power connector etc) then you can leave it out. Otherwise you should select a diode with sufficient current handling capacity for the load and a reverse blocking voltage higher than your highest expected supply voltage. Also make sure the forward voltage drop still allows the regulator to have sufficient drop out voltage.